# get max value of each grid cell in raster file using R

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have one raster file given below

class      : RasterLayer .

dimensions : 3500, 7000, 24500000  (nrow, ncol, ncell).

resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)

extent     : -130, -60, 20, 55  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

source     : data.tif

names      : data

values     : 0.8032204, 113.9562  (min, max)

i am new into raster stuff , i am assuming raster have dimensions of 3500*7000 , so for that each raster grid i want to calculate maximum value value , how i can do it? i didn't have any code sample to show as i only know how to load raster file in r , using raster or terra pckage

thanks for help in advance